# classes and paths

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm having problems with a class and it's path...

Player.as, Line 4 1172: Definition Stream could not be found.

/main.as

```
import player.Player;
var _Player = new Player();
```

/player/Player.as

```
package player {
 import flash.display.Sprite;

 import Stream; // Can't find Steam

 public class Player extends Sprite {
  public var _Stream = null;

  public function Player(){
   var _Stream = new Stream();
  }
 }
}
```

/player/Stream.as

```
package player {
 import flash.display.Sprite;

 public class Stream extends Sprite {
  public function Stream(){

  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

import player.Stream;

I hope this helps

Comment: main.as, Line 22 1120: Access of undefined property _Stream.

Answer (score 0):

Your import statement should be

```
import player.Stream;
```

Imports always use the convention [package(s)].[Class].  Using a tool like [FlashDevelop](http://www.flashdevelop.org/wikidocs/index.php?title=Main_Page) which automatically creates the import statements for you can make this problem much easier to avoid.

Comment: By default, yes.  You can change the behavior by going to File->Publish Settings, go to the Actionscript tab, and click "Settings".  The lower half of the window is the paths which your .fla will look to for classes.  By default one entry is set to '.' which means the same directory as the .fla, but you can add others (and delete the default) to point to whatever directory you would like.